# output of the map reduce values of one key together

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I work on MapReduce with the Wordcount example:
Input data:

```
text files
```

Output:

```
term: fileName  occurrences
```

Map output :

```
Term:filename 1 1 1 1 1
```

Reduce output:

```
Term: filename occurences
```

Example of the code final output "reducer output":

```
Iphone: file1 4
Iphone: file2 3
Galaxy: file1 2
Htc: file1 3
Htc file2 5
```

Output I want

```
Iphone: file1=4 file2=3
Galaxy: file1=2
Htc: file1=3 file2=5
```

How can I get this case, I thought about using the partitioning function, put I don't know how to do that? Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: example of the code output - is your mapper output??

Comment: @siddharthajain no from the reducer output "final output"

Comment: What is your key in map output and what is its format?

Comment: @siddharthajain the map key is a composite key of (term : filename), its format "composite key" that I create it, like the tutorial here: https://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/11/14/mapreduce-composite-key-operation-part2/

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to achieve the output you want but since you have mention about to do it with a partitioner let's do it with that.

According to your question you need to create a partitioner on key on basis of which you want to divide output which is "Term" (iphone, Galaxy etc) .I am assuming here that your map output key format and value format is text if not make changes accordingly. This is what your partitioner should look like

```
public class Partitioners extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Partitioner<Text,Text>{
// I have the written the code if there are 3 reducer(since you have 3 type of key).
//Tip: your number of reducers should be equal to the no of batches you want to divide your map output into.
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
                String Skey = key.toString();
        //Again make changes according to your requirement here but I think it will work according to the composite key you have mentioned
        String term = Skey.substring(0, Skey.indexOf(':'));
        if(term.equals("Iphone"))
        {   // this will send all the key having iphone in reducer 1
            return 0;
        }else if(term.equals("Galaxy"))
        {   // this will send all the key having Galaxy in reducer 2
            return 1;
        }
        else{
           // this will send all the key having other then Iphone and galaxy which is Htc in your case in reducer 3
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now once partitioner is done we need to inform our driver class about this thus add following in your driver class

```
job.setPartitionerClass(Partitioners.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(3); //since we want 3 reducers
```

This will divide your map output in 3 partitioner and now you can reduce the output accordingly in reducer class.

I hope this solves your problem. If not let me know.

Comment: So thanks to you siddhartha for your answer, very very thanks. In my case I have many files and inside these files many terms so I think the partitioning idea not fit with my case,cause I will do many "if statement" for all terms. I try the method you mentioned above but I got an exception say "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException" on the partitioning class that I add. Please, can you tell me for another way to get this output. I try to write StringBuilder and I append the value to it but I don't got the output I want, may because the key is a composite?

Comment: Can you tell me more about error log and you can try or you can change the structure. Of. Composite key

Comment: what's the ways that you say I can do it without the partitioning function, because I can't deal with all terms that I have in the partitioiner.                 this is the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.h.Driver$Partitioners.<init>()
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:527)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:613)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)

Comment: at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hadoop.PATC.Driver$Partitioners.<init>()
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
 ... 4 more
17/02/25 03:10:57 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/02/25 03:10:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
17/02/25 03:10:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0

Comment: other way is to by customizing setup method of mapper. Can you upload your whole code on a git hub repository or any other such website so that I can take a look on whole code because through the logs you have shared in comments I can not figure out anything